# Trying to get specific elements from an observable array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to get specific values from an observablearray. In this example I'm trying to get the number of two values I have created in a array.

I have set the code up like this:

HTML

```
<div id="test" style="width: 100%">
    <table style=" width: 50%; display: block; float: left; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none">
        <tr>
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: someArray()[0].number"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: someArray()[1].number"></span></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-2.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        someArray: ko.observableArray([]) //
    }

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

    $(function () {
        getData();
    });

    var getData = function () {
        viewModel.someArray([
            { 
                number: 123,
                text: "abc"
            },
            { 
                number: 456,
                text: "def",
            }
        ]);
    }
</script>
```

I have also uploaded it to [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4wqtp/1/).

How can I access specific positions in the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works:

```
var viewModel = {
  someArray: ko.observableArray([]) //
}


var getData = function () {
  viewModel.someArray.push(
    {number: 123,text: "abc"},
    {number: 456,text: "def"},
    {number: 789,text: "ghi"}
  );
}

getData();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

You were pushing an array into viewModel.someArray rather than 3 separate objects.  You also have to apply the bindings after inserting the array objects or else you will get a cannot parse binding exception when there are no rows in someArray.

You might consider using the foreach binding to better fit your needs [Knockout Foreach Binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html).  Then you can call applyBindings anytime.  If you're going to have other rows in the array that you don't want, create a [computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) array out of the indices that you do want and build a foreach binding around that.

Answer (score 1):

Your fiddle doesn't work for a few reasons, the biggest being that you're trying to use JQuery, but it's not loaded into the page.

Here's the modified javascript that works:

```
var viewModel = {
    someArray: ko.observableArray([]) //
}


var getData = function () {
    viewModel.someArray.push(
        { 
            number: 123,
            text: "abc"
        });
    viewModel.someArray.push(
        { 
            number: 456,
            text: "def",
        });
    viewModel.someArray.push(
        { 
            number: 789,
            text: "ghi",
        });

}

getData();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```